# HTML element on top of Canvas/Stage

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs

I have a HTML element (position:absolute) positioned over my canvas/stage (createjs). For some reason the element is not visible.

The HTML element contains some buttons, so if i click in the area the buttons are in the suddenly become visible.

Is there a trick to having HTML elements on top of the canvas/stage?

Update: This only occurs on mobile.On desktop version things are layered and properly visible.

Comment: do you need correct prefixes, and also i had similar problem i with absolute position elements on mobile and zindex. What i did it use 'transform: translate3d(0, 0, 10px);` change 10px value until it was infront. Dont forget to set perspective value and preserve 3d

Comment: In what browsers does this occur, and what markup causes it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [`z-index`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) css property.

Comment: Yea i tried that. The element is still not visible until i tap in the are where it is and then it becomes visible. I tried setting z-index of canvas and the html element, i tried setting the z-index dynamically after the stage.update(). Nothing works. Also a note -- it looks fine on desktop, the issue us on mobile.